# Deleting the default vlan on HP Procurve 5406 switch

Tags: hp, hp-procurve

I´ve tried to delete the default vlan on the switch multiple times, via CLI and using the menu options by Telnet, but it keep showing the message= "The default VLAN cannot be deleted". There are no ports assigned on that vlan. ¿Is there a way to delete it?

Comment: It seems to me that the default VLAN can't be deleted on HP switches, just as it can't be deleted on Cisco and Dell switches.

Comment: ***WHY*** would you want to do this?

Comment: simple, security policies

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't delete it.

Instead, just don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be deleted one you log in to the switch as manager

**config

no vlan *Vlan Number*

save

exit**




Done

Comment: Will that work for the *default* VLAN?

Comment: @womble No, it doesn't: `Default VLAN can not be deleted.`